# Sum of Multiple values in different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to use SUM() but it has been not working, maybe I'm using it wrong.

This is how my tables are done, I have 3: destiny, hotel and reserve

```
              Table 1 = destiny
               des_id | des_name   | des_price
                1     | Brazil     | 800         
                2     | Paris      | 900  

              Table 2 = hotel
              hot_id  | hot_name  | hot_price
              1       | Snowflake | 200
              2       | Aurora    | 300

              Table 3 = reserve
              res_id | hotel_id | destiny_id | res_total
                 1   |    1     |     1      |
```

I want that the res_total = hot_price + destiny_price of the selected IDs in the reserve, but I'm getting a abusrd amount that should not be happening like the total being 6000 or 23000.

This is the code I've been trying:

```
Select res_id, (Sum(hotel_price) + Sum(destiny_price)) as res_total            
from reserve, hotel, destiny             
group by res_id;
```

Comment: Hint:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Where is the WHERE clause?

Comment: Cross Join results in # records in Table 1 * records in table 2 * records in table 3 then your summing.  vs INNER JOIN on appropriate Keys...  Put simply... you have no definition on how the tables relate so all records are being joined to all records in each table.  Usually a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query lacks join conditions, such that every tuple is connected to every other tuple (cartesian product, cross join). Try the following query:

```sql
select r.res_id, ifnull(sum(d.des_price),0) + ifnull(sum(h.hot_price),0)
from reserve r
  left join destiny d on r.destiny_id = d.des_id
  left join hotel h on r.hotel_id = h.hot_id
group by r.res_id
```

The query assumes that `des_id`and `hot_id` are keys in `destiny` and `hotel`, respectively. The query can handle situations where `destiny_id` and/or `hotel_id` in a reservation are not filled out (therefore the `left join` and the `ifnull` in the statement).

Comment: What does the r and the d in "from reserve r" and "left join destiny d" mean? or what do they do?

Comment: they serve as aliases for the respective table; for example, by defining `from reserve r`, you can refer to attributes of table `reserve` as `r.destiny_id` instead of `reserve.destiny_id`. Sometimes aliases are just abbreviations, but sometimes they are essential, e.g. if you use the same table multiple times in the same query. OK?

Comment: Yeah, I understood thank you, but it is still not working. It is still giving me a error: "Unknown column" although the column are correct.

Comment: can you post your schema / create table statements? I saw, for example, that your query refers to `hotel_price`, whereas your demo data has no such column but instead a column `hot_price`...

Comment: I figure it out, i had the column right but the table name wrong. Thank you for the information and the advices/hints!